# Using Universal Links for DeepLinking in Push Notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am investigating using Universal Links in Push Notifications for Deep Linking into an iOS app. This is so I can future-proof for web. 
A lot of the examples and tutorials assume the user will select a universal link from a web-site to deep link into an app.
I want to use Universal Links in Push Notifications instead of the regular URL Schema approach. 
I have read the Apple docs 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

However, I am unclear on at this point if I am just using the Universal Link to open the App via a Push Notification, do I still need to set up all the configurations such as creating and uploading an apple-app-site-association file to the root of the web server.

Is this approach to using Universal Links in Push Notifications to Deep Link into an area of the app a recommended approach since Apple seems to be discouraging the use of URL Schema's in general or are Push Notifications a special case?

Comment: Where did you get info about "Apple seems to be discouraging the use of URL Schema's in general "? Never heard about that.

Comment: Kambala - Apple is adopting Universal Links since at least 2015, they had a video about it in their 2017 WWDC. The following post describes their approach https://blog.branch.io/uri-schemes-and-universal-links-for-ios/

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't mean that old-style URL schemes are discouraged: it's still perfectly fine to use them.

Comment: From Apple Docs...Universal links give you several key benefits that you don’t get when you use custom URL schemes. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Push Notifications and Universal Links are two different animals although they both serve to get the user into the application.

With a Universal Link, Safari on the iOS device is opened first in case the app isn't installed. If the app is present, the user is immediately bounced to the app from Safari with the URL passed to the AppDelegate method [application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application). If the app isn't present, Safari opens the URL of the Universal Link. Setting up the apple-app-site-association file is necessary here to validate that you own the destination URL in question and can redirect users from the web site to the app instead. Universal Links are better for user-initiated interaction (clicking a link in an email, etc.)

Push notifications on the other hand communicate directly with the device over TCP/IP to pass the message from APNs to the iOS device (see [APNs Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) for more info).   Safari isn't involved and the user taps the notification on the iOS device (for example) to open the notification and go to the destination.   Your destination isn't passed by URL like with Universal/deep links, but with extra JSON in the notification payload that you can process in your app (see [Creating the JSON Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) for this structure).  There is no apple-app-site-association with push notifications as there is no web site involved. You are communicating directly from APNs to your app and using certificates typically to ensure that only you can open your app with a push notification. Remote push notifications are great for developer-initiated interaction to engage the user.

Hope that helps clarify things!

Comment: Half answers my question... I know the difference between Push and Universal Links. Urban Airship uses deep linking but in examples they have a URL Schema in the payload which is of format com.company.appname://section/asset . I would like to have a typical web style link in the payload instead www.companyname.com/sectiion/asset. The reason for this is I can resuse this link across web platforms in the future. I am proposing placing a web link in the Push Notification payload instead of a URL Schema type link so when the device receives the Push it can use the link in the payload to deeplink

Comment: Ah, makes more sense what you're saying now.   Question didn't mention that you were using Urban Airship.   Assuming you're talking about the Deep Link [Message Action](https://docs.urbanairship.com/workflows/actions/) and using a universal link there. I'm not familiar with UA's whole flow but if they are using Safari to then open the app (typical universal link flow) you would have to set up apple-app-site-association file. You'll need it anyways for normal universal links from web, email, etc. Custom URL types are still supported just fine as @Kambala mentioned.

Comment: Yes custom URL types are still supported but as I mentioned in my comment to @Kambala, Apple emphasises the benefits of Universal links over URL Schemes. The Urban Airship flow has 2 options, simple PN which will open the app and if you don't use their SDK and handle the push yourself you can probably extract the URL from the PN payload and open the correct View in the App. Rich PN's in UA open a webView in the App and when you tap on the link in this case you will be redirected to safari, unless you had implemented Universal Links using the app-association file..in theory.

Comment: The reason this is acutely different is that Universal links are used in  scenarios where the user is external to the App, e.g. in Safari and deep linking into the app. In this case the universal link is being triggered from a web-link from within the App and hopefully iOS is smart enough to realise that